# async.js - separating parallel initilaization from execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

Using [aync.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) how can I push asynchronous functions onto   `async.parallel()` and execute later?

Currently I add my functions, [aync.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) runs them and returns the results in a callback.

```
async.parallel(
{
  f1: function(callback) { callback(null,1); },
  f2: function(callback) { callback(null,2); },
  f3: function(callback) { callback(null,3); }
},
function(err, results) { ... }
});
```

The problem is, all the asynchronous functions (`f1, f2, f3`) must be added at the same time.

How can I build-up the queue of functions, and execute them later?

Is it possible, using control flows such as `async.parallel` and `async.series` or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency)? You can push "tasks" or functions into the queue as in an Array. You can process them serially or in a parallel fashion, using the `concurrency` option (you can change them runtime).